# Trying to use virtualenv with vs code, files are python 2 instead of 3 when interpreter is python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

I tried using select python interpreter and chose my virtualenv using python3 but when I use print(sys.version) on the file I create in vs code, I still get python 2.7. What am I doing wrong?